# Message from Python Socket Server has an extra character in the message?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Whenever I run this code the message that is printed has a "b" in front of it. Why is this? I can not locate where it is coming from. Is is part of the encoding or just extra text in the datagram? How would I fix this issue if it is that?

The message printed is:
Message from Server b"Hello UDP Client"

Client Code:

```
import socket

msgFromClient       = "Hello UDP Server"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromClient)
serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)
bufferSize          = 1024

# Create a UDP socket at client side
UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Send to server using created UDP socket
UDPClientSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, serverAddressPort)

msgFromServer = UDPClientSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0])

print(msg)
```

Server Code:

```
import socket

localIP     = "127.0.0.1"
localPort   = 20001
bufferSize  = 1024
msgFromServer       = "Hello UDP Client"
bytesToSend         = str.encode(msgFromServer)

# Create a datagram socket
UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind to address and ip
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
print("UDP server up and listening")

# Listen for incoming datagrams
while(True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)

    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]
    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)

    # Sending a reply to client
    UDPServerSocket.sendto(bytesToSend, address)
```

Comment: It's a bytes object that you're sending, youcan encode it back to utf-8 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/byte-objects-vs-string-python/

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's being printed like that is because sockets communicate using byte objects. `b'Hello'` is just a byte sequence string and is equivalent to `'Hello'.encode('utf-8')`. To remove that `b` string prefix you have to decode that string using the `decode` method like this:

```
b'Hello'.decode('utf-8')
```

Just decode the message you received before printing it and you'll be fine.

Comment: How would I use that method with the variable msg? ```msg.decode('utf-8')```

Comment: @jw yes, that'll work, this is just like using string methods on variables

Comment: It worked on the client side but whenever I try to do ```clientMsg = "Message To Server: {}".format(message[0].decode())``` on the server side it does not work?

Comment: @jw Does it output any error or it just outputs the string with the `b` string prefix?

Comment: @jw edit your question to contain the edited codes of both client and server side, that'll help us to see where it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you need to decode the response from  bytes back to a string.

```py
msg = "Message from Server {}".format(msgFromServer[0].decode())
```

Apart from that, you should be following PEP8 rules for naming, and making these utils as functions would help reusability of the code:

`client.py`

```py
import socket


def run_client(ip, port, message, buffer=1024):
    message_bytes = message.encode()

    sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(message_bytes, (ip, port))

    response_bytes = sock.recvfrom(buffer)[0]
    response = response_bytes.decode()

    print(f"Message from Server: {response}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_client(
        "127.0.0.1", 20001, "Hello from the UDP Client"
    )
```

`server.py`

```py
import socket


def run_server(ip, port, response, buffer=1024):
    response_bytes = response.encode()

    sock = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((ip, port))
    print("UDP server up and listening")

    while True:
        message_bytes, address = sock.recvfrom(buffer)
        message = message_bytes.decode()

        print(f"Message from Client {address}: {message}")

        sock.sendto(response_bytes, address)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server(
        "127.0.0.1", 20001, "Hello from the UDP Server"
    )
```